# Selenium driver doesn't open a browser window (python)

Tags: python, selenium

I've read some selenium guide and decided to rewrite a simple piece  of code in python to open "Google" page.I've tested the example given in that guide

```
        import unittest
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

```
    class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        def test_search_in_python_org(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("http://www.python.org")
            self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
            elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
            elem.send_keys("pycon")
            elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
        def tearDown(self):
            self.driver.close()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

This example works perfectly.But,my rewritten (and almost copypasted)) script doesnt even opens a firefox tab.Here is my script

```
        import unittest
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

```
    class Googletest(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        def test_log_to_system(self):
            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("http://www.google.com")
            self.assertIn("Google", driver.title)
            elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
            elem.send_keys("hello")
            elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
            assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
         def tearDown(self):
            self.driver.close()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

The funniest thing is - when I simply change the example code in that "example.py" file - script for "Google" works.When I write a new piece of code in a new ".py" file - code doesn't work.Idk maybe it's some "python-selenium-windows stuff" or smthn.I would really appreciate some every useful answer.

Comment: Here is the guide btw http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/

Comment: function name need to start with 'test' so that unittest will run it. change log_to_system to test_log_to_system and try

Comment: Thanks for this reasonable mention this "test" is really important.But the script still doesn't work

Comment: function call should be unittest.main()

Comment: Please update your code with changes you made (like changing your `log_to_system` function name)

Comment: @Anil Thank you those brackets () made the script work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @Anil there were troubles with "test" in function's name (needed to change from `log_to_system` to `test_log_to_system` ) and brackets in function call (`unittest.main` must be changed to `unittest.main()` ) thanks everybody for your help. The problem is solved